# In iOS, How to remove UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView in UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift

I found, the `UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView` in the leftItem above! I want to remove it or `CGRect.Zero`. Thanks!

[image]

ADD:

add leftItem Before in hierarchy:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvwmv.jpg)

After I add a leftItem in hierarchy:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
let image = UIImage(named: "search-icon-blue")
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
let leftItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

let spaceItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
spaceItem.width = -10

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [spaceItem, leftItem]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1dK1.jpg)

When button clicked,it become dark!
But it not become dark when I click left area,I think the reason is UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView above it!
So, I want to remove it!

Comment: How did you add this `UINavigationBar`?

Comment: This code is in UIViewController,The UIViewControler is RootViewController of UINavigationController!

Comment: What is the purpose of `spaceItem` here?

Comment: Make the leftItem close to the left!

Comment: You can't remove `UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView` as it is default property for Navigation Bar. You can just show or hide your added `UIBarButtonItems` here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = nil
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
```

Comment: it is still here.

Comment: Can you add more informations to your question about this actual controller and the code you've used to make your tries?

Comment: Good. Have you tried to launch this code in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: This imageView is a system view,it is not visible, because i don't set image to this imageView.I think The imageView affects My item.When i click the item left area,the item not became dark! ...`viewDidAppear ` is also not work!

Comment: According to your question code when you make `let leftItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)` you initializes a new item using the specified custom view.
When you remove the button items from the navigationItem and refresh the layout, you will haven't any left button items.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = nil;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsLayout];
```

Or you can use:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsLayout];
```

Swift:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = nil
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
```

Comment: It is still here,too!

Comment: Are you using `NavigationController` or only the `NavigationBar`?

Comment: I add my question.

Answer (score -1):

set 
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)